# Multiple UITextFields with UIPicker and UIKeyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, uipickerview

So I have about 7 textfields and 6 of them use a keyboard and the other uses a picker. The problem I'm having is that if the keyboard is open when the textfield that is linked to the picker is touched the keyboard won't dismiss and the picker appears under it. Here's my code

```
- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
 {    
pickerView.hidden = YES;
if ([textField isEqual:state])
{   

    [state resignFirstResponder];
    [self textFieldFirstResponderOnDelay1];




}

else
{
    pickerView.hidden = YES;

    // This movie the view up so textfield isn't hidden by keyboard
    CGRect textFieldRect =
    [self.view.window convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];
    CGRect viewRect =
    [self.view.window convertRect:self.view.bounds fromView:self.view];

    CGFloat midline = textFieldRect.origin.y + 0.5 * textFieldRect.size.height;
    CGFloat numerator =
    midline - viewRect.origin.y
    - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION * viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat denominator =
    (MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION)
    * viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat heightFraction = numerator / denominator;

    if (heightFraction < 0.0)
    {
        heightFraction = 0.0;
    }
    else if (heightFraction > 1.0)
    {
        heightFraction = 1.0;
    }

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation =
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
        orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        animatedDistance = floor(PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
    }
    else
    {
        animatedDistance = floor(LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
    }

    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

    [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}





}


-(void) viewDidLoad
{
pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
pickerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 245, 320, 216);
pickerView.delegate = self;
pickerView.hidden = YES;
pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
state.inputView = pickerView;

[self.view addSubview:pickerView];
}


-(void)textFieldFirstResponderOnDelay1
{ 
pickerView.hidden=NO;
[pickerView reloadAllComponents];
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
if([textField isEqual:state])
{

}
else
{
    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y += animatedDistance;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

    [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}




}
```

Comment: How are you displaying the picker view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding the pickerview as a subview of your main window, just set it as the input view for the appropriate textviews, then it will show/hide as the keyboard would normally:

```
textField.inputView = pickerView;
```

Comment: If I don't add it as a subview it wont appear if I just set the textfield's inputView.

Comment: Don't set it to hidden or anything, just create the picker view, and set it as the text field's input view.  All of the text field's methods will handle showing and hiding the pickerView

Comment: So where do I initialize the picker? You are saying I don't have to?

Comment: The picker view does still need to be initialized.  This can either be done in interface builder, or the way you are now.

Comment: Can you update your question with your code for how you are initializing the picker view, and assigning it as the text field's input view?

Comment: Updated it. It is driving me crazy.

Comment: You do not need to add the picker view as a subview of anything, or ever call setHidden:YES or setHidden:NO on it, this is managed by the textField.

Comment: Wow that was so simple. I though you still had to add it as a subview. Thank you so much.